# How to determine Percent of a range?

Tags: percentages

I have a range and a target. I want to determine that target is how percent of range.

for exam:

```
Minimum = -54
Maximum = 96
Target = -19.5

Result = 23%
```

The result `(-19.5)` is `23%` of the range `(-54 .. 96)`.

How can I calculate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result can be obtained by

$$\dfrac{-19.5-(-54)}{96-(-54)} = .23$$

$$\dfrac{x_{target}-x_{mn}}{x_{max}-x_{min}}$$

Comment: Thanks you. I just have to multiple it to 100.

Comment: You are right and you are welcome